# Что такое шляпы и почему на enSO мне предлагают нажать кнопку "I love HATS", a на ruSO сразу заявляют что я не заработал не одной?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Появилась кнопка на верху страницы. Что это? и почему-то отличается поведение на англоязычном и русскоязычном StackOverflow.

Comment: Постарался ответить на ваш вопрос развернуто в публикации «[Анонс Winter Bash 2015](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2064/)».

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Шляпы - это декорации для аватаров участников, которые выдаются с 14 декабря по 4-е января за определённые действия. См. http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/

На большинстве сайтов, участие в этом мероприятие автоматическое, хотя можно отказаться нажав "I hate hats" в меню под снежинкой в верхней навигации. Исключением является en.SO - ввиду огромного числа пользователей, там нужно кликнуть I love hats, чтобы включиться в действие.

Answer (score 9):

Это ежегодное сумашествие на сайтах сети Stack Exchange. За действия на сайте вы зарабатываете разные шапки. У каждой шапки есть своё задание (типа заработайте серебряный бедж). Вы можете "одевать" свою аватарку в них (или не одевать). Исчезнут они 4-го января. Есть так же [табличка у кого больше](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

Ну а вся информация [по ссылке](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)