# Что такое "Секретная шляпа"?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Что означает "Это секретная шляпа" на месте описания шляпы? Очень часто такое вижу. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для обычных шляп условие получения известно и описано непосредственно в [каталоге шляп](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/). Для секретных этого нет. Такой подход добавляет больше азарта, т.к. становится интересно узнать причину получения или попытаться её угадать исходя из названия или изображения. Раскрытые условия получения секретных шляп регулярно (ежегодно) публикуются на мета сайтах, например, на главной MSE под меткой [`secret-hats`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secret-hats).

Comment: Где можно почитать про эти шляпы? Зачем они, что с ними делать(ну кроме одевания) и главное, а что будет на выходе? Я в этом первый раз участвую

Comment: @SwaD например, [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/176217).